# In Blazor client, how to create a component for an interface?

Tags: .net-core, blazor

From reusabilty point of view, I want to create a component for an interface. So I use it with different concrete objects.

For example, the interface is like this

```
interface ICalculation
    {
        double Calculate();
    }
```

and the Test component is

```
<button @onclick="(() => SetResult())">Set</button>
@result

@code{
double result;
ICalculation Calculation;
void SetResult()
{
result = Calculation.Calculate();
}

}
```

so some where else in another component/page I have some thing like this

```
<Test  inject CalculationA />
<Test  inject CalculationB />
```

So I want to inject Different Calculations into different instances of this component. How can i get this?

I thought using dependency injection of net core, but that is for to inject one object for an interface.
Why important? It helps me to override requests to api, for example, admin and user have different requests but they see the same page structure.

Comment: can you clarify your quetsion? You asked how to create a component for an interface - then later show code where the interface is just being used as a model - which would work fine with DI by the way.

Comment: I get the feeling you want the same component for all users, with different Calculations injected depending on roles? If you could edit your question to make it clear whether this is specifically about inheriting an interface in a component OR about injecting different instances from DI based on Roles, that might help

Comment: You can pass parameters to a component. maybe you can pass an instance of the calculator directly. Or you pass the Type of the name of the Type as parameter and within your component you create an instance via `system.Activator.CreateInstance<ICalculation>(type, false)`. Did not test this, so dont know if it works. But think about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Test component you would make it a normal parameter:

```
[Parameter]  
public ICalculation Calculator { get; set; }
```

and then in 'some where else'

```
@inject CalculationA  CalculationA  
@inject CalculationB  CalculationB  

<Test  Calculator="CalculationA" />
<Test  Calculator="CalculationB" />
```

Or replace those '@inject` lines with normal instantiations (2x) because with multiple implementations you can't do DI on the interface anyway.